# javascript close not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a parent web form which has a child window opened on button click

I need to do is on direct closing of parent form while the child window still open, the child window should close as well.

I have written the following javascript for it

```
var opengridacc;

function OpenGridAccounts(companyId, checkRequestType, documentId) {

    var hdnDocumentId = $(document).find('#hdnDocumentId').val();

    documentId = hdnDocumentId;  


    opengridacc = window.open("../CheckRequest/GridAccounts.aspx?comp_id=" + companyId
                                 + "&CheckRequestType=" + checkRequestType
                                 + "&DocumentId=" + documentId,
                             "GridAccounts",  "height=755px,width=1280px,center=yes,status=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,left=0,top=0");

    return false;

}



function closegrdacc() { 

    if(!opengridacc) {

        opengridacc.close();

    }

}
```

But ie gives an error i.e. close is undefined

Comment: Don't you mean if (opengridacc)?  With the ! operator you're checking if opengridacc does NOT exist!

Comment: unable to get property 'close' of undefined or null reference is the error which I get

Comment: Even if I comment the If condition, the same error occurs

Comment: You need to check if opengridacc exists, or you will get the error.  Again, try "if (opengridacc) {…"

Comment: When I refresh the page the 'opengridacc' gets undefined

Comment: I want to check when user freshely visits a page that time all child windows of that page should get closed

Comment: if opengridacc is undefined, you don't want to call close on it-- you'll get an error.  only if it's defined, and a valid window reference, can you call close on it.  In closegrdacc, whenever you call it, you need to check that opengridacc is defined to avoid an error.

Answer (score 0):

Change closegrdacc as shown below

`function closegrdacc() {
    if(opengridacc!=null) 
{ opengridacc.close();
}
}`

Comment: here with this code I am getting 'opengridacc' as unundefined

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
if(opengridacc!=undefined) { opengridacc.close(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the evaluation is `true`.

```
function closegrdacc() {
    // this would return false if either opengridacc is null or undefined
    if(opengridacc) {
        opengridacc.close();
        opengridacc = null; // clean up for a new call
    }
}
```

In addition you would probably also want to check whether it exists already when opening

```
var opengridacc;

function OpenGridAccounts(companyId, checkRequestType, documentId) {
    if (opengridacc) // it has already been assigned a window
        return false;
    var hdnDocumentId = $(document).find('#hdnDocumentId').val();
    documentId = hdnDocumentId;  
    opengridacc = window.open("../CheckRequest/GridAccounts.aspx?comp_id=" + companyId +
                              "&CheckRequestType=" + checkRequestType +
                              "&DocumentId=" + documentId,
                              "GridAccounts",
                              "height=755px,width=1280px,center=yes,status=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,left=0,top=0"
                             );

    return false;

}
```